# Is it possible to hide specific column in Grid?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxpython with wx.Grid...
I have a general grid with many columns -created with `SetColumn(self, column)` , I want to be able to show and hide specific columns based on user security permission.

I read that `self.SetColMinimalAcceptableWidth(0)` might be useful? How do I use it on specific column? How do I restore the column to original size when I need to show it?

Answer (score 3):

The Grid manual has the following entry:

HideCol(self, col)

```
Hides the specified column.

To show the column later you need to call SetColSize with non-0 width or ShowCol to restore the previous column width.

If the column is already hidden, this method doesn’t do anything.
Parameters: col (int) – The column index.
```

So in the case of self.Mygrid:

```
self.Mygrid.HideCol(0)
```

would hide the first column.

Comment: For completeness, this wasn't available in wxPython 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Under wxPython 2.8:

```
grid.SetColMinimalAcceptableWidth(0)
grid.SetColSize(col, 0)
grid.ForceRefresh()
```